# Force change the subviews frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I set frame for all UI elements in `ViewDidload` and changing their frames in

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

The problem is when I try to Navigate from `View A --> View B` in portrait and then change orientation landscape comeback to View A <-- View B. Then frames are not chaning accordingly.

I tried adding

```
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

But still frames are not changing even viewWillTransitionToSize is not getting called when it comebacks.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-hSelecViewHeight);
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        scrollView.bounces = true;
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];




         imagePager = [[KIImagePager alloc]init];
            imagePager.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width*0.563);
            imagePager.delegate = self;
            imagePager.dataSource = self;
            imagePager.slideshowTimeInterval = 2.0;
            [imagePager setImageCounterDisabled:true];
            [scrollView addSubview:imagePager];

    -- and few other UI elements also --
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColor;

        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

            hSelView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-hSelecViewHeight,self.view.frame.size.width,hSelecViewHeight);
            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-hSelecViewHeight);
            imagePager.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width*0.563);
            [hSelView reloadData];
            if (categoryIndex!=0){
                tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, (259*[[arrListData valueForKey:@"sub_category_name"] count])+100);
                [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, ([[arrListData valueForKey:@"sub_category_name"] count]*259)+100)];

            }else{
                tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, imagePager.frame.origin.y+imagePager.frame.size.height+1, self.view.frame.size.width, (259*[[arrList valueForKey:@"name"]count])+100);
                [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, ([[arrList valueForKey:@"name"]count]*259)+(self.view.frame.size.width*0.563-40)+100)];

            }

    }
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {
         UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
         NSLog(@"orientation:- %ld",(long)orientation);

         if (!isMaximized) {
             content.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-(self.view.frame.size.width/1.5)-10, self.view.frame.size.height-hSelecViewHeight-10-((self.view.frame.size.width/1.5)*0.563), self.view.frame.size.width/1.5, (self.view.frame.size.width/1.5)*0.563);
             closePopButton.frame = CGRectMake(content.view.frame.size.width-40, 5, 36, 36);
             hSelView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-hSelecViewHeight,self.view.frame.size.width,hSelecViewHeight);
             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-hSelecViewHeight);
             imagePager.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width*0.563);
             [hSelView reloadData];
             if (categoryIndex!=0){
                 tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, (259*[[arrListData valueForKey:@"sub_category_name"] count])+100);
                 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, ([[arrListData valueForKey:@"sub_category_name"] count]*259)+100)];

             }else{
                 tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, imagePager.frame.origin.y+imagePager.frame.size.height+1, self.view.frame.size.width, (259*[[arrList valueForKey:@"name"]count])+100);
                 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, ([[arrList valueForKey:@"name"]count]*259)+(self.view.frame.size.width*0.563-40)+100)];

             }


         }


     } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {

     }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add for updated code in viewWillAppear method.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {   

  }
```

Comment: I did, its still same

Comment: @Codecracker show viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear method codes

Comment: Please check YourView  set is `clipsToBounds` is Enable or not. if  incase is set `NO`  please set `YES`.

Comment: @Codecracker When you comeback in your 1st viewController then `(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator `

This method are called or not ?

Comment: no , its not getting called when i come back to first view controller

Comment: OK @Codecracker can you please call this method in `viewWillAppear `  by self ?

Comment: i stuck at that point @miteshmewada with i have to pass UIViewCoordinator and size to it

Comment: Whatever you're doing in `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, you should probably do in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead. Those are sent both on a rotation and when the view controller's view first comes onto the screen, **and** UIKit updates the view's frame before calling `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: How to call programatically this method     `[self viewWillTransitionToSize:self.view.frame.size withTransitionCoordinator:[self transitionCoordinator]];` in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

Call `viewWillTransitionToSize` method in `viewWillAppear`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self viewWillTransitionToSize:self.view.frame.size withTransitionCoordinator:[self transitionCoordinator]];
}
```